# C++ data type best suited for physics vectors like velocity

Tags: c++, data-structures, physics

Beginner programmer here. I want to find the best data structure in C++ to deal with physics vectors such as position, velocity, etc.

Currently I'm using `std::array<double,dimension>`, where the dimension is fixed throughout the program, but it's not terribly convenient since there is no built-in arithmetic operations. I read about `std::valarray` but a lot of references discourage using it, and something like `std::vector` is not optimal since the dimension is fixed.

Is there such a type or should I stop being lazy and overload the `std::array` operators?

Comment: You could use [*composition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) to make your own e.g. "vector" class that implements the suitable operations for a vector. This "vector" class could then use e.g. `std::array` internally to store the data (or use discrete variables). This is a common concept in other physics frameworks.

Comment: Overloading operators for builtin classes is a rather bad idea. Writing your own structure is what you want in this case, and it could wrap the array internally.

Comment: Or, considering that physics and emulation or simulation of it is becoming quite common, there are quite a few libraries and frameworks already that can be used. A quick search should find most of them.

Answer (score 2):

There are vector math libraries you can get, and some of them are free for academic use.

To roll your own isn't difficult, but what you should do is create your own class that contains the std::array or std::vector, provide forwarding methods that you might need (like array index), and math overloads as you need them. Ideally it should be a template class, like std::array is, so you can specify the dimension at compile time as you currently do.

It is not a good idea to add operator overloads to the standard containers for integral types, as you never know what other code you might compile that happens to contain the same container, and would clash.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GCC you can use [GCC's SIMD extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html).

Example - [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CiC9pIYCjN6KSMla):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <x86intrin.h>

typedef double v4d __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (sizeof(double)*4)));

int main(){
    v4d x{1,2,12};
    v4d y{3,4,2};
    auto z = 1.5+x*y;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        std::cout << z[i] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```